# MVC ModelState and EntityFramework Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a edmx model done by Database First and generating the DBSet with the VS tools. I extended with partials the classes to add dataannotation validation to it.
I am receiving on my controller the view model which I am manually controlling the validation of fields. So eventhough I have a required field on my partial class, I am removing it once in my controller ModelState.Remove("pasajeros[" + count + "].numResidencia"); because of some conditions.
Before, I was using LINQTOSQL and I had no problems. But now Entity framework is not honoring my customization of ModelState.
How do i propagate or GO about this issue with EntityFramework?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your view models and Entity models separate. Put your validation annotations on your view models. Then use a tool like [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map the Entity to ViewModel fields for you.

On edit you validate your view model then update your Entity fields which you then save.

Comment: I fully agree with Jasen, see this example project which uses validation and automapper : https://github.com/StefH/KendoGridBinderEx/tree/master/KendoGridBinderEx.Examples.MVC